# Select Radio Button if a Dropdown is Selected

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm wondering how I can use JavaScript to accomplish the following:

I have an input area with five dropdownlists, and each one has a corresponding radio button. When a dropdownlist is clicked to make a selection, I would like the radio button paired with it to become checked right then. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code or a jsFiddle.

Comment: Where's the effort? Show us what you have tried already.

Comment: I'm completely new to javascript, so I'm looking for some help getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kind of simple really. Here is a small code for you.
ID the 5 listboxes as "sel1", "sel2" ,...
ID the 5 radio buttons "rad1", rad2,.. Make sure the radio buttons have same name though!

Next, put this function in as a javascrip:

```
function makeSelection(radioid){
document.getElementById(radioid).checked=true;
}
```

In the select boxes, attach onchanged listeners:
ie;

```
<select ... onchange="makeSelection('rad1');" >.. for the 1st select box,
<select ... onchange="makeSelection('rad2');" >.. for the 2ns select box, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for you response! However I'm not getting any reaction after making a drop down selection...the radio button is not checking. I'm passing the exact ID of the rbtn control to the function.

Comment: function makeSelection(radioid){alert(radioid);} <<- does it alert?
Also, have you defined the function BEFORE <select ..

Comment: My dropdowns are custom controls, so I had to add the onchange property. Now the function is firing, but i'm getting a null error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: is null? Well I hope you have passed an argument to the function as shown in the example. ie; "makeSelection('rad1');" if its not passed correctly, the error will appear (p.s - hard to put it in layman words :) )